# Spherical polar coordinates in a tetrad frame

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra

I am looking at a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0608278) which writes the spatial components of a vector $S_i$ in terms of spherical polar coordinates w.r.t the local tetrad frame as (Eq 33 in the linked paper),

$$ S_1 = s \sin \theta \cos \phi, S_2 = -s \cos \theta , S_3 = s \sin \theta \sin \phi$$

Now, intuitively, I think of $S_{1,2,3}$ as corresponding to the $x,y,z$ components of the vector.

If this is correct I would then expect $S_2 = s \sin \theta \sin \phi$ and $S_3 = s \cos \theta$, in accordance with the [usual definition of spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Why are the $S_2, S_3$ components 'switched' in this way?

Thanks

Comment: There's more than one convention for how to write spherical components, as noted correctly at the Wikipedia entry that you linked. Is it explained by that alone? (I haven't dug into the paper that you referenced to try to trace it through.)

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 1):

I did not have a look at the paper you referenced.

But, the coordinates they use make sense. This is a right-handed coordinate system. It looks like the following one where $\vec{S}=(S_1, S_2, S_3)$ with $s=|\vec{S}|$:

[image]

You should understand why they use this choice of angles. But, this is a "normal" spherical coordinate system.